# Observable race condition - code gets executed too fast

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

in my code I export a csv file. Before the export happens, I need to modify some data. But while I do this, I'm experiencing a race condition. While the id gets set correctly, the number only gets updated after the method got called a second time.

I think the error is, that the return gets executed before the observable finished. How can I solve this?

```
  public exportAsCSV(
    arr: ArrEntity[],
    origin: string,
    id?: string,
  ): Observable<Blob> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();

    if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
      headers = headers.append(
        xxx
      );

      if (origin === 'table') {
        this.getValues(3).subscribe(() => {
        for (const a of arr) {
          a.id = id; //works fine

          a.number = this.getNumberById(a.number); // only correct after 2nd call
         }
        });
      }

      return this.http.post(
        url,
        {
          chargeLogEntities: arr,
        },
        {
          headers: headers,
          responseType: 'blob',
        },
      );
    } else {
      return Observable.of();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. If you depend on some data that should be fetched asynchronously, you should proceed with your logic only after the data is received (in a callback, or in `.then` of a Promise or in `.subscribe` of an Observable).

An alternative solution is to chain multiple Observables using `flatMap/switchMap/concatMap` operators.

Your code can look like:

```
public exportAsCSV(
    arr: ArrEntity[],
    origin: string,
    id?: string,
  ): Observable<Blob> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();

    if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
      headers = headers.append(
        xxx
      );
      
      let preconditions$ = of();

      if (origin === 'table') {
        preconditions$ = this.getValues(3).pipe(
           tap(response => {
              for (const a of arr) {
                 a.id = id;
                 a.number = this.getNumberById(a.number);
                 // this is a very bad approach, try not to mutate objects/arrays
                 // ideally you'd want to return a modified array and use it in your http.post or in further .subscribe methods
              }
           })
        )
      }

      return preconditions$.pipe(
         switchMapTo(this.http.post(
           url,
           {
             chargeLogEntities: arr,
           },
           {
             headers: headers,
             responseType: 'blob',
           },
         )
      )
    } else {
      return Observable.of();
    }
  }
```

If you want NOT to mutate the array, your solution might look like:

```
public exportAsCSV(
    arr: ArrEntity[],
    origin: string,
    id?: string,
  ): Observable<Blob> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();

    if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
      headers = headers.append(
        xxx
      );

      let resultingArray$ = of(arr);

      if (origin === 'table') {
        resultingArray$ = this.getValues(3).pipe(
           map(response => {
              return arr.map(arrayItem => {...arrayItem, id: id, number: this.getNumberById(arrayItem.number)}
           })
        )
      }

      return resultingArray$.pipe(
         switchMap(resultinArray => this.http.post(
           url,
           {
             chargeLogEntities: resultinArray,
           },
           {
             headers: headers,
             responseType: 'blob',
           },
         )
      )
    } else {
      return Observable.of();
    }
  }
```

The `.pipe(switchMapTo())` or `.pipe(switchMap())` guarantees that the code will be executed one after another

Comment: Hey, thanks for your advice! With Promises it's working now. Unfortunately, with the second code example, I receive the following error: Type 'Observable<void[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ChargeLogEntity[]>'.
  Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'ChargeLogEntity[]'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ChargeLogEntity'.ts(2322)

Comment: just add generics to your `this.http.post<object[]>` - replace with the type you receive from the backend